# hide storage volume in conjure-up instance

Tags: juju, openstack, openstack-autopilot, storage, conjure-up

I got conjure-up working on a single node system and I have launch 2  instances up and running and I assigned 20GB storage to this instance. If run `df` command inside instance it still shows my host storage volume which is a 250GB SSD. Is there way to hide it so you can't see the host storage disk inside of instance:

Basically hide `/dev/sda1`.

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8175592        0   8175592   0% /dev
tmpfs            1639180     9468   1629712   1% /run
/dev/sda1      229528788 35786740 182059540  17% /
tmpfs            8195884        0   8195884   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            8195884        0   8195884   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1         48256    48256         0 100% /snap/lxd/5866
/dev/loop0         89088    89088         0 100% /snap/conjure-up/924
/dev/loop2         83584    83584         0 100% /snap/core/4110
/dev/sdb       961303584   492388 911956684   1% /storage
tmpfs            1639180        0   1639180   0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 0):

**conjure-up** uses `dir` as the storage backend in **lxd** which installed in Nova instance. `dir` storage backend does not support quotas.

You should change storage backend of **LXD** in **Nova**